# jquery get children except with condition from an inner element

Tags: jquery, children

I have

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <span class="except">None</span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span>One</span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span>Two</span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span class="except">All</span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I want to get all `li` of `<ul>` except the one with the span with class `except`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('ul li').not(':has("span.except")')
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ZbvDP/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var $lis = $("ul li").filter(function() {
    return $(this).find("span.except").length == 0;
});
```